# Android: Http request fails in wifi connection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, picasso, android-glide, android-connectivitymanager

I have an issue with HTTPS requests. I do not know why? But I have been observing that in the same wifi(mobile hotspot) youtube and Instagram loads very well. But in my app, I have tried Picasso, Glide, OkHttp, HttpURLConnection, etc. These all take time to get a response. I have a list of 20 image URLs all are CDN(if I open these URLs in the browser it takes max 40ms or less, if the internet connection is very slow then takes 1-2sec). When I connect to another mobile hotspot Picasso, Glide, OkHttp, and HttpURLConnection take a lot of time, which means more than 20 sec,  `after 20 sec the mobile data speed suddenly goes up to Mbps and it loads all the images` but at the same time, Instagram & youtube maintain the consistent internet connection and my main issue is, why the first response takes time? but at the same time, Instagram & youtube works very well.

**ERROR**

```
 class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1
```

**Yes I'm getting the issue when I connect to that specific mobile hotspot.** When I connect to other hotspots it works well. But I have a doubt **How do Instagram & youtube manage to achieve good speed?**

**Are there any techniques to force hardware or any kind of different code they are using?**